# Google CloudVPN don't activate SA when GKE packet are sent to OnPrem SVC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

I’ve a project with a custom mode VPC network, a CloudVPN (IKEv2 with static routes) in a EU region and a GKE cluster in AU region. Here the CloudVPN configuration:

[CloudVPN Tunnel configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8W3a.png)

My VPN endpoint OnPrem is a Cisco ASA 9.1 and Tunnel goes RUNNING for CloudVPN and for ASA the following SA is UP (I can't understand why only 10.128.0.0/255.128.0.0):

```
  local ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.128.0.0/255.128.0.0/0/0)
  remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.144.0.16/255.255.255.240/0/0)
```

I’ve configured the kube-dns with an OnPrem DNS (reachable in VPN) but if I try to resolve an OnPrem service I’m not able.

I see the UDP packet exit from GKE node, I’ve the route to VPN GW and necessary FW rules and also I see the ASA log about ACL applied packet. But I don’t see the CloudVPN/ASA trying to pull on the relative SA and the packet to exit from ASA.

If I ping GKE instance from OnPrem DNS server the relative VPN SA goes UP and, after that, my containers are able to resolve OnPrem services!

I can’t understand this behaviour, someone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Does the gke adress range is on the remote ident if the ASA? If not, it seems to be the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is. If I rewrite the remote network IP ranges (on both sides) with 0.0.0.0/0 everything works. It seems to be an incompatibility on ASA platform: the CloudVPN gateway think that all SA are UP, the ASA instead thinks only 10.128.0.0<-> 10.144.0.16 SA is UP.